# VideoViewでの動画再生で15秒進めると動画が止まることがある

Tags: android

Android 4.4.2で`VideoView`を使って動画再生を行っています。
動画はネットワークからhttp live streaming形式で配信をしています。

ボタンを押すと

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
videoView.seekTo(videoView.getCurrentPosition() + 15000);
videoView.start();
```

が呼ばれ、15秒進むといった処理を行っていますが、うまくいくときとうまくいかないときがあります。うまくいかないときには、動画画面が止まったままで再度ボタンを押しても動きません。
なぜこのような事象になるのでしょうか？また解決方法などもあればご教授お願いします。

Comment: サーバー側ではなくこの部分が問題だと判断された理由は何かありますか？また掲載のコードは動画の時間の流れに対して、現時点から15秒戻るようになっていませんか？

Comment: サーバーからの同じHLSストリームをiPhoneの再生プレイヤーで再生してシークしても問題なくシークできます。そのためAndroidのVideoviewの問題かと思っています。また15秒戻る機能もありましてコピー＆ペーストミスです。質問を修正しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

以下のようにやってみましたが、現象は再現されませんでした。
止まることなく再生されます。

目的の動作は
・動画の準備ができたら、あらかじめ指定した秒数だけシークされて動画が始まる
・その後、問題なく再生される
でよいでしょうか。

```
    String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";
    //String VideoURL = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";


    VideoView videoview = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    try {

        mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                this.getActivity());
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoview.seekTo(videoview.getCurrentPosition() + 15000);
            videoview.start();

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mediacontroller.setEnabled(true);
                    mediacontroller.show(0);

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Videoviewの下に早送りボタンがあり、そのボタンを押すと15秒だけ進んで再生されます。つまり何度もボタンを押すとその回数だけ進みます。初回だけではありません。私のアプリではsetOnPreparedListenerのonPreparedでstart()メソッドを呼び出さず、パスをセット後にすぐにstart()メソッドを行っていました。調べてみると非同期ということがわかったので、setOnPreparedListenerのonPreparedでstart()メソッドを行うように修正しました。しかし、状況変わらずです。うまくいくときといかないときがあります。なお、配信データは3gpではなくHLS(m3u8)です。この辺が原因とかありますか？

Comment: `MediaController`は使わず、独自のボタンで制御しているということですね。

Comment: 再現しました。m3u8の時のみ、まれに`E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1004)`というログがでて止まりますね。

Comment: 今調べていますがなかなか手間取っています

Comment: 涙が出るほど嬉しいです。こちらも試行錯誤しています。ありがとうございます。